# Android - Identify whether Web-view playing sound or not

Tags: android, webview

the web page loading inside webview is auto playing in background, i would like to detect when sound stops and than display toast message.

thanks

Comment: any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: What have you tried so far? As of right now, I don't see any code or indication that you've put any effort into solving this yourself.

Comment: @esme_louise i have tried different ideas non works for me, just keep changing one code to another....

Comment: Load network page or the loacal page in WebView?

Comment: index page and mp3 inside assets folder

Comment: Try my solution below, and I suggest you should learn how to use the javascript callbak in WebView frist !

Comment: @Fou Can this method solve your problem?

Answer (score 13):

That's can be easily if you use the `JavascriptInterface`. Follow my step:

1.Create a interface callback:

```
public class MediaWebInterface {

    public MediaWebInterface() {

    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void setEndedIndex(int pIndex) {
        // Call when the audio ended.
    }

}
```

2.Create a javascript that contain an "ended" listener:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>window.onload=function(){var n=document.getElementsByTagName("audio"),r=n.length;for(var o=0;o<r;o++)n[o].setAttribute("index",o),n[o].addEventListener("ended",function(){for(var e=0;e<r;e++)this===n[e]&&window.external.setEndedIndex(e)})}
</script>
```

3.Load the html data into a `String` and append above javascript to you html data `String`:

```
// Enable javascript support
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new MediaWebInterface(mHandler), "external");
mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(mBaseURL, mHTMLData+aboveJavascript, null, "utf-8", null);
```

4.When the audio stop, and it will call the `MediaWebInterface.setEndedIndex(pIndex)`, and pIndex is the index of the audio.

Hava fun, and try it!

Please read the [WebView.addJavascriptInterface()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String)) first!

**Warnning:** If you use proguard, you should add follow script into your `proguard-project.txt`. Otherwise, the callback will invalid. Because the class name and method will obfuscate, so the javascript can't callback.

```
//Preserved javaScript interface class
-keepclassmembers class com.xxx.xxx.javascript.MediaWebInterface {
   public *;
}
```